# apache rewrite rule issue with country header

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Fastly + Adobe AEM (cloud) add a header to each request called x-aem-client-country.  This has been verified using a servlet to dump the headers.  AEM uses a "dispatcher" in front of the servlets, which is basically apache.

The following should re-direct to our "not allowed from your country" error when being hit outside of UK, but does not work.

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-aem-client-country} !^GB$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/uk/en/errors/location-error.html
    RewriteRule ^.*$ /uk/en/errors/location-error.html [R=307,L]
```

Have we made some silly syntax error?

If we dump the headers from a servlet, we see the required header:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
x-aem-client-country:DE
Server-Agent:Communique-Dispatcher
X-Forwarded-Proto:https
```

AEM works by only specifying the http vhost (it terminates ssl outside, or falls back to the port 80 vhost, not sure which).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you already solved this issue but now we are using the same technique to redirect the user in the dispatcher. I managed to make it work using uppercase when I refer to the header. Also because of the conditions that I have here it only applies the rewrite rule when the request url looks like [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-AEM-CLIENT-COUNTRY} ^US$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /content/${CONTENT_FOLDER_NAME}/us/en/home.html [PT,L]
```